# Back Up Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, backup, rsync, tar

I have a dual boot system installed on my pc (Ubuntu 17.04 & Windows 8.1)
and I'd like to back up the Ubuntu partition on external HD.

Some info:

## fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     616447     614400   300M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2      616448     819199     202752    99M EFI System
/dev/sda3     1081344 1172967549 1171886206 558,8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  1172969472 1953523711  780554240 372,2G Linux filesystem
```

Ok so I've looked around a bit and found a few ways to do this:

A) tar

B) dd

C) rsync

Now, from what I understood:

- "tar" command would basically just compress and copy the directories one        wants to back up into a .tgz file which can then be moved to my external HD. It     can also be used with bzip2 to compress even more.
- "dd"  command creates a .dd image of the wanted partition. So it would make a full back up each time.
- "rsync" command is used for incremental back ups. It basically looks for and saves only the files that have been added or changed since the last back up.

I've never even attempted to do a back up so I've got a lot of questions to ask.

Let's say one has his nice back up file on his external HD and one day decides to restore it for some reason:

1) Can It only be done on the same machine the back up was created?

2) Can It only be done on the same OS the back up was created?

Other questions:

3) Let's say I do a full back up of my Ubuntu partition with tar, can I then    use rsync to add the changes and basically update my "backup.tgz" file?

EXAMPLE:

```
cd /
sudo tar -cvpzf /backup.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found  --exclude=/backup.tgz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /
```

Can I then do:

```
sudo rsync --delete -av /backup.tgz  /
```

?

EDIT:

Ok so, I've backed up the / directory with :

```
sudo tar -cvpzf /Ubuntu_17.04_ROOT_BackUp-date+%d-%m-%Y.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/Ubuntu_17.04_ROOT_BackUp-date+%d-%m-%Y.tgz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /
```

It took a couple hours but my back up file (of 64.3 GB) was created.
This was the terminal output at the end:

```
tar: /: file changed as we read it
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Is this a standard output at the end of a back up with tar or something went really wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at Clonzilla? It is a stand alone drive image/backup tool similar to ghost; however, incremental backup is not yet supported. Information and a CD image can be found here http://clonzilla.org PS - rsync clones (makes two directories Identical) it doesn't image.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'd prefer not to install new programs if I can use the terminal.

Comment: It is not an install it runs from the CD. As far as running from terminal, I think  you will find difficulty with imaging the entire partition that you are running from. And of course restoring a running system will be problematic.

Comment: I suggest that you make two kinds of backup: 1. complete backup of the whole internal drive with Clonezilla once in a great while, maybe four times per year; 2. backup of your personal files with a shellscript using `rsync` or another more dedicated backup tool (in both cases incremental backup) that you can do frequently, every night, every week or at least whenever there are new data that you don't want to lose. See for example this link, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Comment: Please consider that you cannot rely on a backup that you have not tested. You need an extra drive of at least the same size as the internal drive, that you want to backup, in order to test a complete backup. And you should test it by recovering from the backup data into the extra drive without any 'help' from the current internal drive. If it does not work, you must modify the backup procedure or recovery procedure. It it a good idea to do this before you really need the backup ;-)

Comment: So you are telling me that in order to test my back up and make sure it's right...  I need another PC?? What if I don't have another?

Comment: You don't need another PC, but to test a complete backup you need another drive (HDD or SSD) of at least the same size as the drive, that is backed up. You can test the incremental backup in a simpler and maybe more intuitive way without an extra drive. For example, the backed up files created by `rsync` will be available to read with any program. You can compare them to the original files and check that no important file is omitted.

Comment: I think, but am not 100% sure, that `tar` is designed to manage creating a tarball (the [compressed] archive file) in the same directory that it is backing up. But I would write the tarball to another drive, for example an external drive. `tar` can be made to stay within a file system (partition) with the option `--one-file-system` 'stay in local file system when creating archive'

Comment: Since you are not using a ready-made [GUI] application program for backup, you should spend time to check it. I suggest that you inspect the result of your backup and test it in a way, that will not damage the current system in the internal disk(s). Ony you know how you want it, and you may need some fine tuning to backup exactly what you want (not more, not less), and that it is possible to restore. If you need detailed help, please *ask very specific questions*. It makes it easier to give relevant advice.

Comment: Yep, you are right once again, I should have backed it up directly on my External HD. Can I now try to  move the back up to the external HD and uncompress the file IN the external HD to see what it copied?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Normally the leading root directory is stripped from the file paths, so that it is not overwriting the source files. But to be sure, you should at least test it with the `t` command, `tar -tvf ...` to check that they will be written locally. It is even safer to check it with the internal drive removed and booted from a USB pendrive (and the external HDD connected of course).

Comment: I think I' ll choose the first option - adding the 't' command -  the second  is more complicated. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65392/discussion-between-idk-and-sudodus).